# Find the max value in multidimensional lists without knowing how many elements there are

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing some code for my coursework in School but my idea requires me to find the max value in some different arrays. It seems quite easy but the main problem is that I will not know how many elements in the list there are because my list contains result every time a user has done my quiz. For example, if my list contained:

```
main_list=[["Name1",[21,22,25]],
          ["name2",[26,21,24]],
          ["name3",[29,21,24]]]
```

Every time my main program is executed it will add another element to the list. So if it was executed again my list would become:

```
main_list=[["Name1",[21,22,25]],
          ["name2",[26,21]],
          ["name3",[29,21,24]],
          ["name4",[21]]]
```

So you see that I will not be able to see how many elements there are. Yet I need to add up the 2nd element in the 2 dimensional lists (`main_list[0][1] + main_list[1][1] + main_list[2][1] etc.`) and find biggest value in them.
How would I do this?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your question. It will be easier to find an answer for your specific problem, when you show, what you have done so far: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I reckon `max(max(l[1]) for l in main_list)` might be what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array without knowing it's size and create a dict that represent each name with his max value.

```
main_list=[["Name1",[21,22,25]],
          ["name2",[26,21,24]],
          ["name3",[29,21,24]]]


res = {sub_list[0]: max(sub_list[1]) for sub_list in main_list}

print (res)
>>> {'Name1': 25, 'name2': 26, 'name3': 29}

print (max(res.values()))
>>> 29
```